# Необходимо контент с одного html разнести по разным php

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

У меня есть такая html-ка

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- article TEXTS BLOCK -->
<section id="text-article-1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</section>
<section id="text-article-2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</section>
<section id="text-article-3">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</section>
</html>
```

И 20 php файлов такого типа конструкции

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<section id = "article-1">
    <? require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/content/gallery-1.php";?>
    <!-- PLACE FOR ARTICLES 1 -->
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне необходимо в файлы php чем-то по типу include включить селекты следующим образом - в файл php 1 в `<!-- PLACE FOR ARTICLES 1 -->` вставить из html select с id 1, в php 2 select с id 2 и тд. Чем бы мне это сделать?

Comment: обычно так не делают

Comment: почему не использовать один файл с условиями для `select`?

Comment: Похоже на "проблему XY". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY